# error 1215: cannot add foreign key contraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm getting the

`error  1215`: 
`cannot add foreign key contraint on my sql script.`

I have already checked the other question about this problem and the answer is always you have to set the same type.

Well, I have the same type for the foreign keys but I get this error.

Here is the code of my sql script:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS CarLoan;

USE CarLoan;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CarLoan`.`sede` (
`id_sede` INT NOT NULL,
`nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`citta` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`via` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`telefono` VARCHAR(9) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_sede`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CarLoan`.`impiegato` (
`cf` CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
`nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`cognome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`id_sede` INT NOT NULL,
`mail` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`cf`),
INDEX `id_sede_idx` (`id_sede` ASC),
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_sede`)
REFERENCES `CarLoan`.`sede` (`id_sede`)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CarLoan`.`direttore` (
`cf` CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
`nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`cognome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`id_sede` INT NOT NULL,
 `mail` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`cf`),
INDEX `id_sede_idx` (`id_sede` ASC),
FOREIGN KEY (`id_sede`)
REFERENCES `CarLoan`.`sede` (`id_sede`)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: your code is fine, just try with any testing server where this db does not exist and revert the output...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have the error, but in mine, it's ok, the log is following:

```
sql> CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS CarLoan
[2015-11-02 19:59:40] 1 row(s) affected in 6ms


sql> USE CarLoan
[2015-11-02 19:59:40] completed in 3ms


sql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CarLoan`.`sede` (
  `id_sede` INT NOT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `citta` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `via` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `telefono` VARCHAR(9) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_sede`))
  ENGINE = InnoDB


[2015-11-02 19:59:41] completed in 725ms


sql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CarLoan`.`impiegato` (
  `cf` CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `cognome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `id_sede` INT NOT NULL,
  `mail` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cf`),
  INDEX `id_sede_idx` (`id_sede` ASC),
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_sede`)
  REFERENCES `CarLoan`.`sede` (`id_sede`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
  ENGINE = InnoDB


[2015-11-02 19:59:42] completed in 748ms


sql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CarLoan`.`direttore` (
  `cf` CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `cognome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `id_sede` INT NOT NULL,
  `mail` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cf`),
  INDEX `id_sede_idx` (`id_sede` ASC),
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_sede`)
  REFERENCES `CarLoan`.`sede` (`id_sede`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
  ENGINE = InnoDB


[2015-11-02 19:59:42] completed in 472ms
```

Comment: Please indent the output by four spaces, to make it code view, that way it is easier to read.